# What's the best way to apply a "Join" method generically similar to how String.Join(...) works?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, linq, concatenation

If I have a string array, for example: `var array = new[] { "the", "cat", "in", "the", "hat" }`, and I want to join them with a space between each word I can simply call `String.Join(" ", array)`.

But, say I had an array of integer arrays (just like I can have an array of character arrays). I want to combine them into one large array (flatten them), but at the same time insert a value between each array.

```
var arrays = new[] { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5, 6 }, new { 7, 8, 9 }};

var result = SomeJoin(0, arrays); // result = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9 }
```

I wrote something up, but it is very ugly, and I'm sure that there is a better, cleaner way. Maybe more efficient?

```
var result = new int[arrays.Sum(a => a.Length) + arrays.Length - 1];

int offset = 0;
foreach (var array in arrays)
{
     Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, result, offset, b.Length);
     offset += array.Length;

     if (offset < result.Length)
     {
         result[offset++] = 0;
     }
}
```

Perhaps this is the most efficient? I don't know... just seeing if there is a better way. I thought maybe LINQ would solve this, but sadly I don't see anything that is what I need.

Comment: Aggregate, Concat and SelectMany seem to be what you are looking for. Most likely SelectMany.

Comment: I had incorrect answer about SelectMany (missed separator element). Will eventually try fancy aggregate... But manual iteration is probably better (as one need to special case first element).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generically "join" sequences via:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Join<T>(T separator, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> items)
{
    var sep = new[] {item};
    var first = items.FirstOrDefault();
    if (first == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    else
        return first.Concat(items.Skip(1).SelectMany(i => sep.Concat(i)));      
}
```

This works with your code:

```
var arrays = new[] { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5, 6 }, new { 7, 8, 9 }};
var result = Join(0, arrays); // result = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9 }
```

The advantage here is that this will work with any `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, and isn't restricted to lists or arrays.  Note that this will insert a separate in between two empty sequences, but that behavior could be modified if desired.

Comment: using `First` looks like be very nice however this code needs some `empty items` check.

Comment: @KingKing Edited to include that

Answer (score 2):

```
public T[] SomeJoin<T>(T a, T[][] arrays){
   return arrays.SelectMany((x,i)=> i == arrays.Length-1 ? x : x.Concat(new[]{a}))
                .ToArray();
}
```

**NOTE**: The code works seamlessly because of using `Array`, otherwise we may lose some performance cost to get the `Count` of the input collection.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most efficient, but it is quite extensible:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Join<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source, T separator)
{
  bool firstTime = true;
  foreach (var collection in source)
  {
    if (!firstTime)
      yield return separator;

    foreach (var value in collection)
      yield return value;

    firstTime = false;
  }
}

...

var arrays = new[] { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5, 6 }, new[] { 7, 8, 9 }};
var result = arrays.Join(0).ToArray();
//  result = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9 }
```